# .Add(ImageWithallCtrls.Access1)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

Here I have two tables the common code is written in abstract class reaming code

This is my two table columns

```
public class General
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string F_Name { get; set; }
        public string L_Name { get; set; }
        public string Middle_Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
    }
```

Here i'm separating commom code

```
 public abstract class Common
        {
            public string F_Name { get; set; }
            public string L_Name { get; set; }
        }
```

this is my Access1 table code

```
public class Acc1:Common
    {
        public string Middle_Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

this is my Access2 table code

```
public class Acc2:Common
    {
        public string PersonName { get; set; }

    }
```

**Home.cs**

Here I copy both the tables columns in General and when I try to saving table at d.Access1.Add(ee) Here I'm getting error

```
public ActionResult AbsAssClass(General ss)
        {
            Acc1 ee = new Acc1
            {
                  };        
            db.Access1.Add(ee);

                return View();

        }
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Please provide more information so people can answer your question.  What error are you referring to?

Comment: @DavidFunny: Pro Tip: If you want to resolve the error, stop ignoring the error message.  What is the *actual exact error message*?  If it's a type mismatch (which it sounds like it is), what are the types being used here?  What does `.Add()` expect to be provided?

Comment: Where is "db" coming from?  I see no code referencing that object.

Comment: You must not be including all your code.  Please provide all the code so we can see what is going on.  I don't see db being instantiated anywhere.

Comment: `db` is likely being instantiated at the class level.  Which is probably a bad idea, but it's not the issue at hand.  (If `db` was `null` it would be a different error.)  The issue at hand is that you're providing the wrong object type to `.Add()`.  C# is a statically typed language, the types have to match.

Comment: @David more bad can be going on here then meets the eye.

Comment: I cannot comment further until I see all the code.  Too much is missing to fully understand what is going on with this code.

Comment: bro its mandatory code 4r me please provide any url or any code it will solve me like i can save data into database using Abstract class

Comment: @DavidFunny please see my previous comment!

Comment: @DavidFunny: An "alternate solution" to what?  If the compiler is telling you that you're passing the wrong type to the method, then you're passing the wrong type to the method.  Nobody here can change the design of the C# language just to get your code working.  If you can provide more information then we may be able to help more specifically to your case.  But given what we know so far, you're simply trying to do the wrong thing.

Comment: @Mike, I think "db" is DbContext type from Entity Framework...

Comment: We don't do your work for you. Tell us the exact error and explain what you don't understand about it.

Comment: @ Yawar Murtaza he is saying correctly

Comment: @DavidFunny: Since you deleted your earlier comment which had at least *some* information hinting about the error, the question now contains *even less* relevant information.  Nobody here can help you if you refuse to tell us anything about the problem.  `“I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.` - Eric Lippert

Comment: db.Access1.Add(ee); at this point i'm getting error as   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ImageWithallCtrls.Access1>.Add(ImageWithallCtrls.Access1)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(Ima‌​geWithallCtrls.Acces‌​s1)' has some invalid arguments

In this line of code:

```
db.Access1.Add(ee);
```

The `.Add()` method is expecting a type called `Access1`.  But you're supplying it a type called `Acc1`:

```
Acc1 ee = new Acc1();
```

`Acc1` and `Access1` are two different things.

They may (or may not, we don't know) share properties of the same names and types.  They may be *very similar* in many ways.  But they are not the same type.  C# is a statically typed language, so "similar" doesn't count.

Provide the method with an object of type `ImageWithallCtrls.Access1` to save to the database.

Note: It's *possible* that your entire data layer isn't what you need it to be, or that your project architecture is broken in more fundamental ways.  We can't know that, all that is pretty far outside the scope of this question.  Regarding the question at hand, of why you can't save an `Acc1` object to your `Access1` table, it's simply because they're two different things.

Comment: but how can i save the data in access1 table if u r ready i will giive my teamviewr id

Comment: @DavidFunny: You save the data by creating an instance of `Access1`, populating it with data, adding it to the DB context, and saving the changes in the DB context.  There are many Entity Framework tutorials available to help you with this.